# Create Table in SQL using data frame structure object of R

Tags: sql, r, dataframe

How Should I create Table in SQL using the R Data frame object structure with out writing complex code. Is there is a any function in R to accomplish this.

Comment: You will find "writeTable" functions in the packages `RODBC` and `odbc`

Answer (score 2):

if you are using mysql, you can use the dbWriteTable from RMySQL package

```
    library(RMySQL)
      con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
            user="USER_NAME",
                host="localhost",
                password = "PASS",
                db = "NAME_DATA_BASE")

       dbWriteTable(conn = con, name = 'test', value = iris)
```

In this example i put **iris** data frame in table named **test**

Answer (score 1):

In sqlite:

```
library(RSQLite)
#set working directory to where your sqlite database resides
setwd("C:/sqlite/Data")

#connect
sqlite<-dbDriver("SQLite")
my_conn<-dbConnect(sqlite,"my_db.db")

#write out the dataframe in the database
dbWriteTable(my_conn, "new_table_in_db", my_dataframe, row.names=F)
```